# Why does cv2.waitkey function cause error using conda on ubuntu

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, ubuntu, anaconda

I've been using cv2 with anaconda successfully until I added:

```
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

receiving this error:

> cv2.error: -------src-dir-------/opencv-2.4.10/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:562: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvWaitKey

I'm using conda 3.14.0 on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS and the packages in the error
advice are installed

Comment: The order of installation matters. The error message says you must have  `libgtk2.0-dev` and `pkg-config` installed *before* installing `opencv2`.

Comment: I had opencv installed before anaconda. then i installed it again through anaconda. what should i do?

Comment: Did you uninstall `opencv`, install `libgtk2.0-dev` and `pkg-config` and then install `opencv` again?

Comment: I did but im not sure what the anaconda installation did to that. it might be local

Comment: Is this problem fixed? I'm having the same problem here too.

Answer (score 0):

This link may help you. https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/m/#!msg/anaconda/uHB2wYT29vU/80ywinE9BAAJ.

In summary, you can try:

For opencv2.X

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo opencv
```

Comment: shuye I am currently not working with python or opencv or conda so I can't evaluate your answer. if someone can validate I will be happy to acknowledge.